# Execute traverse statement in orientjs

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I'm using an `OrientDB` graph database, I have two vertexes Room and Participant, I have created a few edges between Room and Participant records   and I want to execute the following command using `orientjs` driver:

```
select from (traverse out() from (select from room where name='room test 1')) where @class='Participant'
```

Updated

I have in mind to use something like this:

```
db.let('firstSelect', function(s){
     s.select().from('room').where({name:'room test 1'});
}).let('traverse', function(s){
     s.traverse('out()').from('$firstSelect').while('$depth<=1');
}).let('finalSelect', function(s){
     s.select().from('$traverse').where({'@class':'Participant'});
}).commit()
.return('$finalSelect')
.all()
.then(function(participants){
    console.log(participants);
})
```

In the future I will put this code in a function with some parametters

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `db.query` API:

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2424,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});

var db = server.use({
    name: 'OrientJStest',
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});

db.query('select from (traverse out() from (select from room where name="room test 1")) where @class = :inputClass', {
    params: {
      inputClass: "Participant"
    },
    limit: -1
}).then(function (results) {
    console.log('Vertexes found: ');
    console.log();
    console.log(results);
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but meanwhile I replaced `orientdb` with `postgres`.